# Can you access the IP address of the current logged in user through Apex code?

Tags: apex, api, login, userinfo

Is there an API for getting the current IP address that you can use in Apex code? I didn't see anything in UserInfo, and I don't want to use the LoginHistory object at all for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to query `AuthSession.SourceIp`.  An `AuthSession` record with a `SessionType` of [SubstituteUser](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_session_types.htm) is created when you log in as another user.

Comment: Danke schön!  Using it in a Login Flow.